# Именно в связи с этим

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, грамматика

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые в этом предложении?

*Именно в связи с этим она и была вынуждена вести решительную борьбу.*

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Запятые в этом предложении **не нужны.**

Нераспространенный оборот "в связи с этим" не обособляется, частица "именно" относится к обороту.

Из словаря

**ИМЕННО.** I. частица. 1. (употр. для подчёркивания какого-л. члена предложения, для указания на него). Как раз.

В СВЯЗИ С (кем-чем), в зн. предлога.

Answer (score 2):

Запятые в предложении *Именно в связи с этим она и была вынуждена вести решительную борьбу* **не нужны**. Объяснение [здесь](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1737297-v-svjazi-s-etim-nuzhna-li-zapjataja.html).